# Need to stop a thread and join from the thread routine itself

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have working on a state design pattern in C++ where I have multiple states. Some states have thread routine bounded by `pthread_create`. Now there are cases where one state make a transition to another state and thus the thread needs to be stopeed and memory needs to be cleaned by `pthread_join`.

So in summary I need to stop the thread from the thread-routine itself.
How can I achieve this?

Or is there a way that when the thread-routine is completed the memory clean-up happens automatically?

PS: Problem is, when I make a state transition to another state from the thread routine current state destructor is called. Inside the destructor of the current state I need to stop and join the thread. Otherwise there is a memory leak happening.

Comment: In my experience, trying to have threads self-end or detaching threads leads to a lot of problems. I have found that multi-threading is much simpler to implement if you have a clear hierarchy or thread ownership. Whoever started the thread should eventually join it, or delegate ownership to another thread (which will then join it). One possibility is to change your state machine to have an overarching thread which owns all the individual state threads.

Comment: By "memory clean up" do you mean the memory occupied by the thread itself and its stack, or do you mean something else, such as memory dynamically allocated by or on behalf of the thread?

Comment: Problem is : when I make a state transition to another state from the thread routine of the current state destructor of the current state is called. Inside the destructor of the current state I need to stop and join the thread (from the thread routine itself). Otherwise there is a memory leak happening.

Comment: "Joining" literally means joining two thing together. "Joining a thread" is no exception, that means that you start with two running threads and afterwards you have one running thread.  Inside the thread routine, how would you select the other thread (the one that continues to run)?

Answer (score 0):

> So in summary I need to stop the thread from the thread-routine itself. How can I achieve this?

Return from the function that is being executed at the bottom of the thread.

> memory needs to be cleaned

You can clean up the thread after it has terminated by joining it from another thread. You can avoid doing that by detaching the thread before terminating it.

---

P.S. Prefer using the portable `std::thread` (or `std::jthread`) instead of system specific threading API.

---

> can u add share code how to terminate a thread from the routine itself using std::thread

Example:

```
auto thread_fun = [] {
    return; // this terminates the thread
};
std::thread t(thread_fun);
t.join(); // this waits for the thread to end, and cleans it up
```

Comment: can u add share code how to terminate a thread from the routine itself using std::thread or boost::thread?